# Can Hibernate dynamic pass a parameter to child set query?

Tags: hibernate, database-design, orm, hibernate-mapping

I got a very special case when I'm using Hibernate:

Our system has a survey module, a single survey has many kinds of questions, and our question presentation information like title, prompt should supports internationalization which can be defined in `database` by administrators, so a single question corresponds several languages of question vocabulary. Following is the ER diagram:
[image]

Here is POJOs:

POJO SurveyModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_survey")
public class SurveyModel extends BasicModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "surveyId")
    private Set<QuestionModel> questions = new HashSet<QuestionModel>();
}
```

POJO QuestionModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_question")
public class QuestionModel extends BasicModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId")
    private Set<VocabularyModel> vocabularies = new HashSet<VocabularyModel>();
}
```

POJO VocabularyModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_vocabulary")
public class VocabularyModel extends BasicModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String language;
    private String title;
    private String prompt;
}
```

So the diagram and POJO relationship shows clearly their relations. Now when user takes the survey, it only needs one single language of vocabulary object for questions at one time, yes, we can get it by filtering manually from vocabulary set which includes all languages of vocabulary, but It doesn't make sense and produces lower performance. In our system, all child set of parent object are `loaded lazy`, so how can I pass a parameter like language to sub query to filter vocabularies set after I get the parent object like SurveyModel here? I was attempting to use `Hibernate Filters`, but It seems to not be matched my case.

Can anybody give me help and ideas? Thanks so much in advance.

**EDIT:** I got another way to do this, get the survey only without obtaining its sub-objects, and then manually query its sub-objects with the parameter like language. But It doesn't make full use of Hibernate. So I'm also want to search for a way within Hibernate to meet my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout working for half a day, I managed to find a solution to solve this problem. It is still the **`Hibernate Filters`**. Following is the explanation for solving it.

1, Define a **`Filter`** on target entity like this:

```
@FilterDef(name="questionLanguage", parameters=@ParamDef(name="language", type="string"), defaultCondition="language='cn'")
```

2, Add the **`Filter`** on the set object

```
@Filter(name="questionLanguage", condition="language = :language")
```

3, Because of Filter's scope is a single **`Session`**, so we need to enable the **`Filter`** and set the paramter before you query your parent entity object.

```
session.enableFilter("questionLanguage").setParameter("language", language);
```

Feel happy for getting this done. ^.^.